# Server alias not working on apache, ubuntu 14.04 server, Amazon AWS

Tags: virtualhost, apache2, conf

I have a remote ubuntu server on Amazon AWS, and I am enabling a site using `a2ensite`. I have a conf file in my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/001-mysite.conf` My servername and server alias is laid out like this

```
ServerName 4techgroups.com  #Works
ServerAlias www.4techgroups.com #Doesn't work http://4techgroups.com #works

    <Directory /var/www/html/site1>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

I don't know why I can't access www.4techgroups.com while 4techgroups.com works. Could it be because it is a amazon AWS server.

Comment: Define 'not working'.

Comment: @AlexD Go to www.4techgroups.com //which doest find the address
Go to 4techgroups.com without the www and it goes to the desired address. That is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain `4techgroups.com` hasn't got DNS record about host `www`. Simply add it to your domain with same ip address as `4techgroups.com` has. Read documentation at [Updating DNS Support for Your VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-updating)

Comment: Thank you @Mikhail . That was exactly what was missing, I had to update my dns record and add www.4techgroups.com as a value. Thanks you and apologies for late response.